# Why does the EU choose to label products from the "occupied Territories" in Israel?

Tags: israel, economy

Israel has wondered aloud why they are the only ones that are having their products labelled even though there are 100s of terrirotorial disputes.
Aside from anti-israel bias - Is there a logical reason?

Comment: Your sources, please? For example, Northern Cyprus products need no separate labelling because **they are embargoed** and only Turkey allows them https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embargo_against_Northern_Cyprus.

Comment: My question was , is there a counter argument to what Israel is responding or is it that they just do not like Israel

Comment: No, your question was "Why only is Israel punished?". Turns out it is not only Israel, in fact by Northen Cyprus standard the "punishment" is quite light. Oh, don't forget economical sanctions against Russia for the Ukraine conflict, too (just from the back of my mind, too lazy to do an extensive list).

Comment: @SJuan76 I think your comment could be a good answer, esp. if you can back up with the details of sanctions against Russia and Northern Cyprus and show that Israel's "punishment" was much lighter in comparison.

Comment: You can ask why this is happening now and not decades ago. I think this is something that is worthwhile to consider in more detail.

Comment: @SJuan76 it is not about punishment, it is more about propaganda. People will be every day reminded that Islael is an occupant. Was a big "J" later in Jewish passports in Nazi Germany a punishment? Not that obviously.

Comment: @Anixx Thank you for the "compare anyone who disagrees with Israel Government politics to Nazi Germany" apportation, I was worried about Internet users suddenly having regained common sense. And yes, it is a measure of pressure (why else would you make the effort to implement it?) but, as stated above, Israel is not the only country to suffer those measures and, in fact, it is a way lighter action than other measures to similar situations.

Comment: @SJuan76 you possibly missed my point. I do not claim it is more harsh pressure measure than those in respect of other countries. But it is more propaganda effective and popular opinion affecting. Also it is very much in line with similar measures of the past (stamping Jewish passports, boycotts of Jewish production and prohibition of cosher meat as "inhumane" and violating animal right as examples), so that smart people easily see the hint.

Comment: @Anixx I did not miss the point. You are mixing a measure against **actions** in violation of international law and several international agreements with measures against **innocent people** based on racial/religious profiling. Is like saying that economical sanctions against Russia for the Ukraine invasion are an attempt to criminalize all Russian people.

Comment: @SJuan76 You see. Measures against other countries are purely economical. This measure against Israel is less economical than singling out, labeling. Producing popular disgust. Reproducing older anti-Jewish propaganda measures. It produces possibly less economic effect but alludes to Christian prejudices.

Comment: @SJuan76 Again you are missing my point. It is less about economics. It produces possibly less economic effect but alludes to Christian prejudices. If you eat this food, you are complicit with Jewish crimes, you like someone who receives profit from execution of Chist or killing Christian babies. It makes people to avoid anything Jewish as "unclean" or "made with blood" even if not labelled. This is very powerful exactly as an anti-Semitic tool rather than making economic pressure on Israel that can make it change policy.

Comment: @Anixx if your point is the Western government agitating neo-nazi groups to get Israel to cede, it is even crazier because a) political suicide b) no actual effect on Israel (victims will be Western Jewish people, attacks would reinforce Israel government claims of being singled out and possible emigration to Israel will add to Israel power) and c) nowadays most people in power knows that such tactics do not come with an "off" switch incorporated so they can easily become uncontrolled. If you claim that Western governments are anti-Jewish, citations please.

Comment: @SJuan76 I do not think the actual aim of this policy is to make Israel to do something. Actually it cannot compel Israel, but this policy's aim is domestic European population. My guess it was suggested by an anti-semite in European bureaucracy as a very subtle, smart and formally invulnerable act of anti-semitic propaganda. Like many measures in Nazi Germany were by the way, the prohibition of kocher meat as violating animal rights already mentioned. It was more effective in compelling the Germans that Jews are cruel to animals than compelling Jews not to eat meat.

Comment: @Anixx with all the due respect, you are just repeating the "anyone who does not agree with Israel Government policies is anti-Jewish". Yes, and anyone who did not like Stalin was anti-Russian, and anyone who does not agree with me is an enemy of Mankind. We get it, it is not that it is a new argument. Your "valuable apportation" and its lack of any evidence has been duly noted, thank you.

Comment: @SJuan76 obviously you are wrong and I never made such claim. You are just ascribing to me something I never said. Just the opposite, my point is this policy has little to do with Israel exactly because as you mentioned a full prohibition of food from disputed territories would had much greater effect on Israeli policy. The point of this measure is mostly or entirely domestic.

Comment: The question creates a false dilemma. The reason could be illogical whilst at the same time not being anti-Israel. And if we look at it, that is the case. Accepting the illegal nature of the occupation, but then allowing products from occupied territories to be sold is illogical and *pro-Israeli*. The logical path would be to ban their sale as is done with products from Crimea.

Answer (score 11):

Products have to be labelled with their origin. Products from the occupied territories are not made in Israel, but in the occupied territories and thus they must be labelled as such. Just as you can't stamp "Made in Germany" on something that is made in France. It isn't anti-French, but rather, a matter of correct labelling.

Comment: Products made in Chinese-occupied territory (e.g. Tibet) aren't labeled as "Tibet" but "China". http://politics.stackexchange.com/a/9269/115. So it's NOT about "correct labelling".

Comment: As far as I know Tibet is not occupied as such, but a part of China. People in Tibet are citizens of China and they follow Chinese law.

Comment: China saying "it's a part of China" doesn't change the fact that China occupied it **and continues to occupy it with force**. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Tibet#1912.E2.80.931951:_de_facto_independence . The only difference is that nobody dares to oppose China due to their trade influence and geopolitical strength on one hand; and Tibetians don't quite have the same international influence Muslims and Arabs combined do; on the other.

Comment: @user4012 Actually (muslim) Uighurs in Chinese-occupied Xinjiang (or Uighurstan as they'd prefer it be known) look on at Tibetans' international influence with envy.

Comment: @user568458 - I wasn't even touching Xinjiang, since there are more ways people can hand-wave that away as "not being occupation". But yes, that situation is far worse for the people wanting independence influence-wise

Comment: @user4012 You totally failed to read what I wrote. Tibet is a part of China. They follow Chinese law. The people living there are Chinese citizens. The areas occupied by Israel does not follow Israeli law and the people living there are not considered citizens of Israel. Thus Tibet is legally a part of China while the occupied areas are not a part of Israel.

Comment: @SVilcans - CHINA decided that, not Tibet. So you're saying that if tomorrow Israeli government decides that Judea and Samaria are "part of Israel" and everyone living there is subject to Israeli law, you'd fully support treating Palestinians (vs Israel) the way Tibet population is treated (vs. China), including no markings? Seriously?

Comment: @user4012 Ah, the one state solution. There are those that favour that one. From a labelling standpoint I guess that would mean products would be allowed to be marked "Made in Israel" since they are made in Israel.

Comment: @user4012 Does the EU recognize China's sovereignty in Tibet? If yes, then it wouldn't be "occupied territory" from EU's point of view. Probably a helpful comparison is Crimea, whose annexation by Russia is not considered legitimate.

Comment: Actually found out that the EU [prohibits import from Crimea](http://www.consilium.europa.eu/uedocs/cms_Data/docs/pressdata/EN/foraff/143342.pdf). So, over the occupation of Crimea, the EU implemented a much harsher measure than simply requiring labelling.